# Sharpdx tookit input won't work with windows 10 universal apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, sharpdx, windows-10

I'm trying out sharpdx tookit with universal app in windows 10 and can't get the input to work. I know I have to create different input for different devices but for now I just want to try keyboard.

So I follow this link first to set up the project: [Is there a SharpDx Template, for a Windows Universal App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456492/is-there-a-sharpdx-template-for-a-windows-universal-app)

And right now I'm trying input like I usually do it:

In the constuctor:

```
_keyboardManager = new KeyboardManager(this);
```

In the update method:

```
var state = _keyboardManager.GetState();
if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.B))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

But he never register that the key B is down (or any other key I have tried). I have also tried GetDownKeys() but the list is always empty.

So does any one have any idea what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And there's an another, better, easier version:

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
using SharpDX.Toolkit;
using Windows.System;
namespace Example
{
    class MyGame : Game
    {
        public MyGame()
        {
            CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += MyGame_KeyDown;
        }
        void MyGame_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey);
        }
    }
}
```

You have to subscribe to the CoreWindow's event, that's it :)

Comment: Sorry for my late comment but this worked perfectly fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

HEUREKA!

I had the same problem, but with windows 8.1. It took me 2 days to find a solution. It's the foolish SwapChainPanel, which can't be in focus because the class doesn't inherit from Control class, so it won't handle keyboard events.

The solution is [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/54e4820d-d782-45d9-a2b1-4e3a13340788/set-focus-on-swapchainpanel-control?forum=winappswithcsharp) that is to say, you have to put an XAML element that's inherited from the Control class, like Button to handle the event. My XAML file is like this:

```
<SwapChainPanel  x:Name="_swapChainPanel"
                 Loaded="_swapChainPanel_Loaded"
                 KeyDown="_swapChainPanel_KeyDown">
    <Button x:Name="_swapChainButton"
            Content="Button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="0" 
            KeyDown="_swapChainButton_KeyDown">
    </Button>
</SwapChainPanel>
```

In the XAML.cs I handled the events this way:

```
private void _swapChainButton_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false; //This will pass the event to its parent, which is the _swapChainPanel
    }

private void _swapChainPanel_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        game.KeyboardEvent();
    }
```

In the KeyboardEvent() method I put the if things... and you have to make the button in focus manually, with code. "_swapChainButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);"

But last, it's not so good for me, it's so slow. It has delay. :/