# Can I develop a Windows Universal Application using DirectX and C#

Tags: c#, .net, directx, win-universal-app

I've seen that there is a template to do so in Visual C++, but not in C#. Have I to stick to C++ to develop a Direct X (Universal) application ??

Can I use C#? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a SharpDx Template, for a Windows Universal App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456492/is-there-a-sharpdx-template-for-a-windows-universal-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I to stick to C++ to develop a Direct X (Universal) application?

Technically, you can use the DirectX in .NET platform by using the interop technology. SharpDX has done such kind of things for you and you can easily use the DX in you .NET project including the Window 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 app project. However, as I just tested, the SharpDX has not supported the Windows Universal App yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you must use C++ when calling DirectX APIs, so if you want to develop your Windows Universal Application by C# and DirectX as the same time, the best practice might be to package all the DirectX related functions in a separate C++ WinRT component. Then you can include it in any C# application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs for DX, you might want to look into the Win2D project from Microsoft, its C# and lets you mix 2d and 3d.