# C#/GDI Converting to Universal Apps for Win10

Tags: c#, c++, .net, win-universal-app, directx-11

I realize someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288858/can-i-develop-a-windows-universal-application-using-directx-and-c-sharp/32302771#32302771) but I think my question is from a different vantage point and I hope it might help people in the future understand their options.

Basic issue: I have written a C# App (obviously managed) as a normal application (non-universal) and in order to support a quick log window above an active typing area, I initially wrote some graphics using pure .net (GDI I believe).  This worked initially but it became VERY slow sometimes and I want way better control over how it looks including some specialized graphics.

What I would like to do is rework the app AND find out which of the following makes the most sense for a Windows 10 Universal Application:

1. Call DirectX Directly from C# (from documentation this is either not-possible or not really ideal, base project for C# does not have directX like C++ does).
2. Call Managed Libraries from C++ and use DirectX as the Application Foundation.
3. Use C++/CLI and call managed code. (I believe this is not possible anymore).
4. Use SharpDX (I looked and it didn't seem available based on a question here).
5. Use another Third Party (such as Unity) but deal with game frameworks.

Other parameters: Since everything is C# already, would like to avoid total rework, however, if it's recommended I'm 100% ok with doing so.  This is not a game application, though it needs performance like one on one of it's screens, it will mostly be driven by interfaces (could be XAML) and network data coming in on a separate thread.  I also have no qualms about learning extensively (say a very different language from C# or C++) in order to complete this project because learning is value.  If I am missing something glaringly obvious that would be great to know about it as well.

Comment: take a look at Win2D http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: That is just the kind of thing I am looking for in terms of options.  I will try to load that into VS2015 Pro tonight and see how far I get.  Thanks!